# How to open image with default device image viewer in Phonegap

Tags: cordova

Lets say my App can download images. I want that the downloaded image will be shown to the user after download has finished and the file has been written into the device.

With this line of code the image will be displayed on the screen.

```
window.open('file:///path_to_image', '_system', ' ');
```

The problem is, I have not a back button. Means if the image is shown I have no chance to go back into my app view. (Until I restart the app)

How did you solved this problem?
Thanks.

Comment: Has anyone an idea how I can resolve this problem?

Comment: take a look at this - http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/fullscreen-image-on-tap/4199

Answer (score 1):

You can use **FullScreenImage-Cordova-Plugin**

Follow the git https://github.com/keensoft/FullScreenImage-Cordova-Plugin  it will help you open the image in full screen natively, upon closing it will return the control to your app.

Comment: This only seems to work with images in packaged along with the app in the www/ folders

Comment: this supports base64 strings too. but do you know how to close the fullscreen preview.